# Applying LDA to a corpus for training using gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have corpus with around 20,000 documents and I have to train that data set for topic modelling using LDA.

```
import logging, gensim

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
id2word = gensim.corpora.Dictionary('questions.dict')
mm = gensim.corpora.MmCorpus('questions.mm')
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=mm, id2word=id2word, num_topics=100, update_every=0, chunksize=3000, passes=20)
lda.print_topics(20)
```

Whenever I run this program I come across this error:

```
2013-04-28 09:57:09,750 : INFO : adding document #0 to Dictionary(0 unique tokens)
2013-04-28 09:57:09,759 : INFO : built Dictionary(11 unique tokens) from 14 documents (total 14 corpus positions)
2013-04-28 09:57:09,785 : INFO : loaded corpus index from questions.mm.index
2013-04-28 09:57:09,790 : INFO : initializing corpus reader from questions.mm
2013-04-28 09:57:09,796 : INFO : accepted corpus with 19188 documents, 15791 features, 106222 non-zero entries
2013-04-28 09:57:09,802 : INFO : using serial LDA version on this node
2013-04-28 09:57:09,808 : INFO : running batch LDA training, 100 topics, 20 passes over the supplied corpus of 19188 documents, updating model once every 19188 documents
2013-04-28 09:57:10,267 : INFO : PROGRESS: iteration 0, at document #3000/19188

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Animesh/Desktop/NLP/topicmodel/lda.py", line 10, in <module>
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=mm, id2word=id2word, num_topics=100, update_every=0, chunksize=3000, passes=20)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 265, in __init__
self.update(corpus)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 445, in update
self.do_estep(chunk, other)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 365, in do_estep
gamma, sstats = self.inference(chunk, collect_sstats=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 318, in inference
expElogbetad = self.expElogbeta[:, ids]
IndexError: index (11) out of range (0<=index<10) in dimension 1
```

I even tried to change the values in `LdaModel` function but I always get the same error!

What should be done ?

Comment: the 11 unique tokens is a little suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your dictionary (id2word) is not correctly matched up with your corpus object (mm).

For whatever reason, id2word (the mapping of word tokens to wordids) only contains 11 tokens
    `2013-04-28 09:57:09,759 : INFO : built Dictionary(11 unique tokens) from 14 documents (total 14 corpus positions)`

Your corpus contains 15791 features, so when it looks for a feature with id > 10, it fails. ids in 
    `expElogbetad = self.expElogbeta[:, ids]`
is a list of all the word ids in a particular document.

I'd rerun the creation of the corpus and dictionary:

`$ python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki`
(from the gensim LDA tutorial).

The logging data for the created dictionary should indicate far more than 11 tokens I believe. I've run into a similar problem to this myself.